# mean value of multiple card draw

Tags: means, card-games

I'm calculating probabilities for a card game that I'm creating. In this game, there are 78 cards in the deck. The cards have the following values:

4 cards have value 1
4 cards have value 2
4 cards have value 3
4 cards have value 4
4 cards have value 5
20 cards have value 1.5
38 cards have value 0

If I draw one card from this deck of 78, the mean value of that draw is 1.13 ((4*1)+(4*2)+(4*3)+(4*4)+(4*5)+(20*1.5)+(38*0))/78.

What is the mean (i.e., expected) value of my hand if I draw two cards from the deck in a single draw? Or three, or four cards?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you draw $n$ cards and $X_i$ denotes the value of card $i$.

The rv's $X_i$ have equal distribution hence equal mean: let's say that $\mu:=\mathbb EX_1$.

$X:=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is the total value of the hand with: 
$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb EX_1+\cdots+\mathbb EX_n=n\mu$$

on base of linearity of expectation.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you for the prompt reply. I admit I don't follow all of the notation (e.g., what is "rv" and does "E" refer to the individual mean while mu is the overall mean?). However, if I understand you correctly, by my calculations, the expected value of a hand with 1 card = 1.15, 2 cards = 2.06, 3 cards = 2.78, 4 cards = 3.38.

Comment: "rv" stands for "random variable" and the $\mathbb E$ is a symbol for expectation. The expectation of a random variable is in fact the mean value of it. If the expected value of a hand with one card is $1.15$ then the expected value of a hand with $n$ cards is $n\times1.15$.